# How do you iterate through custom keys in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, loops

is it possible to create my own custom keys in the asp.net web.config file and iterate through them with C#?  How do you do both (where do I put the key?  what format?)?  I have an application for an intranet that does certain things based upon the IP address of the client.  Instead of hard coding those in the codebehind file, I thought I would put them in the web.config and iterate through that.  That way I could add or remove from my configuration file without recompiling everything.

My key would have a name, IP address, and maybe other information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this should do it for you...

This is in your web.config...

```
<configSections>
    <section name="DataBaseKeys" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</configSections>
<DataBaseKeys>
    <!--Connection Strings for databases (or IP Addresses or whatever)-->
    <add key="dbCon1" value="Data Source=DbServerPath;Integrated Security=True;database=DbName1"/>
    <add key="dbCon2" value="Data Source=DbServerPath;Integrated Security=True;database=DbName1"/>
    <add key="dbCon3" value="Data Source=DbServerPath;Integrated Security=True;database=DbName1"/>
    <add key="dbCon4" value="Data Source=DbServerPath;Integrated Security=True;database=DbName1"/>
    <add key="dbCon5" value="Data Source=DbServerPath;Integrated Security=True;database=DbName1"/>  
</DataBaseKeys>
```

This is your code...

```
using System.Configuration;

using System.Collections.Specialized;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadDdls();
}

private void LoadDdls()
{
    NameValueCollection nvcDbKeys = GetDbKeys();

    //Loop through the collection       
    for (int i = 0; i < nvcDbKeys.Count; i++)
    {
        // "Keys" is the "key" - Get(int) is the "value"
        this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(nvcDbKeys.Keys[i], nvcDbKeys.Get(i)));
    }
}

private NameValueCollection GetDbKeys()
{
    //Declare a name value collection to store Database Key List from web.config
    NameValueCollection nvcDatabaseKeyList;
    nvcDatabaseKeyList = (NameValueCollection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DataBaseKeys");

    return nvcDatabaseKeyList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(VS.80).aspx). That allows you to put your, umm, custom config in web.config, and access it in whichever way you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick-and-dirty solution**: Add your keys to appSettings with an index as postfix, ie. "key1", "key2", etc., and loop until you get to a key that doesn't exist.  Or add a delimited list to a single key, ie. "value1;value2;value3;..".

**Better solution**: Create your own custom section handler, then you can add your data in your own way in a separate section of web.config.  You'll need to define the section and sectiongroup at the top of web.config, with a reference to the section handler class.

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="MySectionGroup">
          <section name="MySection" type="[type and full assembly name]"/>

   ...
   <MySectionGroup>
      <MySection>
         [some xml]
```

Next create the section handler class, it needs to implement the interface *IConfigurationSectionHandler*, which defines a *Create* method.  *Create* takes sectionNode as a parameter, which is an XML node you can parse in whatever way you want.  The return object should contain the data you've parsed.  To load the section handler, write:

```
MySectionDataObject myData = ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "MySectionGroup/Section" ) as MySectionDataObject
```